Problem with the Adobe Merge PDF api in logic apps - bad parameter, invalid type
I have posted this in the Adobe Community also but have not had a reply so I thought I should hit my normal Go-To Community.
I have a Logic App that monitors incoming emails.  Some have multiple PDF attachments that I want to merge and save to Dropbox.  I have it working with the Encodian API but I want to switch it over to the Adobe API.

I then use the array as input for the Encodian API.  When I try this with the Adobe API, I get an error, "bad value for parameter 'files'; invalid type".  Doing some research I read somewhere that I should change the fileName line to "$content-type": "application/pdf"
This still returns the same error.
Even though the files were already PDF's I thought maybe they still needed to be converted to Base64 so I tried that.

The Append array action generates this result:
[
    {
        "$content-type":"application/pdf",
        "fileContent":"SlZCRVJ..."
    },
    {
        "$content-type":"application/pdf",
        "fileContent":"SlZCRVJ..."
    }
]

The error again is: "bad value for parameter 'files'; invalid type".
The full code for the action is:
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['adobepdftools']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "body": {
            "files": "@variables('FileToMerge')",
            "outputFileName": "Temp.pdf"
        },
        "headers": {
            "x-api-key": "PowerAutomate",
            "x-region-value": "-ue1"
        },
        "path": "/operation/v1/combinePDF"
    }
}

Thank you for any insight that can be provided!

Thanks K J.  I did figure things out and was able to get it working.  I posted the solution below. However, your information is quite helpful.  I didn't know that all encoded PDF file strings start with JVBER.  I decoded SlZCRVJ and I now understand what you mean as SlZCRVJ decodes to  JVBER.   So much to learn!  Thank you!

For anyone looking for the same answer, I was finally able to get this sorted out.
If you are using the 'When a new email arrives' trigger, you need to append to the array variable (mine is named 'FilesToMerge' ) using a 'For each' loop based on the trigger body output: triggerBody()?['attachments']
Then append the 'contentBytes' alone to the array: items('For_each')?['contentBytes']
The json in the code view will look like this:
{
    "inputs": {
        "name": "FilesToMerge",
        "value": "@items('For_each')?['contentBytes']"
    }
}

If you view the output of the Array variable with a compose Action, You see a single line of code like this:
["---Code from first attachment---","---Second---","---etc---"] 

The Adobe Merge PDFs action then will look like this:
Be sure to click this button to change the input mode first:

You can then use the output from the Merge PDFs as the content for whatever action you want to use to create the new file.
I posted this to my same question in the Adobe Forum
